# Powershell to Automate AKS Version Upgrade

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-powershell

I'm totally new to powershell, trying to automate the aks cluster upgradation based upon the current version and checking the available versions then update one by one using azure powershell. Here is the code i tried, but getting the following error, so it did not work:

```
Param 
    (    
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] 
        $AKSName
        
     )
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity > $null
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "id" > $null

    $AKsResourceGroup= Get-AzResource -Name $AKSName | foreach {$_.ResourceGroupName}
    
    $AKsLocation= Get-AzResource -Name $AKSName | foreach {$_.Location}
    
#Check Current Version Of Cluster
$CurrentVersion = Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $AKsResourceGroup -Name $AKSName | select -ExpandProperty KubernetesVersion -WarningAction Ignore
 "The CurrentVersion is $CurrentVersion" | ConvertTo-Json

#Check the availability versions to upgrade
$Versions = Get-AzAksVersion -Location $AKsLocation | where-Object {($_.OrchestratorVersion -gt $CurrentVersion) -and ($_.IsPreview -ne 'True')} | foreach {$_.OrchestratorVersion} -WarningAction Ignore
 "These are the available versions $Versions" | ConvertTo-Json

#AKS Upgrade
Set-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $AKsResourceGroup -Name $AKSName -KubernetesVersion $Versions

#To check the status of AKS
Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $AKsResourceGroup -Name $AKSName | Format-Table -Property Name, Location, KubernetesVersion, ProvisioningState
```

**the output**
"The CurrentVersion is 1.23.8"
"These are the available versions 1.24.3 1.24.6"
Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'KubernetesVersion'. Specified method is not supported. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

unable to upgrade the kubernetesversion- need to upgrade to next version based on var CurrentVersion

Answer (score 0):

*I tried to rework the same issue in my environment and got the below results*

Declared the variable like aks name, resource group and the location using below commands

I run the same command but got the same error as mentioned below

[image]

To check the current version of the cluster

```
$CurrentVersion = Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $AKsResourceGroup -Name $AKSName | select -ExpandProperty KubernetesVersion -WarningAction Ignore
 "The CurrentVersion is $CurrentVersion" | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

To check the availability  version to upgrade

```
$Versions = Get-AzAksVersion -Location $AKsLocation | where-Object {($_.OrchestratorVersion -gt $CurrentVersion) -and ($_.IsPreview -ne 'True')} | foreach {$_.OrchestratorVersion} -WarningAction Ignore
 "These are the available versions $Versions" | ConvertTo-Json
```

*Here I am able to see 3 versions to upgrade, at a time we cannot upgrade the 3 versions and we cannot directly upgrade the 1st to 3rd version*
*Hence we are getting the error. To resolve this issue, I have split and converted into final version*

```
$attempt3 =$versions.Replace(' ', ' , ')
$attempt3=$attempt3.replace(' " ' , " ")
$attempt3=$attempt3.replace(" ' "," ")
#for upgrading the latest version
$finalversion=$attempt3.Split(",")[o]

Set-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $AKsResourceGroup -Name $AKSName -KubernetesVersion $finalversion
```

[image]

I am able to see the latest version which I have upgraded

```
Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $AKsResourceGroup -Name $AKSName | Format-Table -Property Name, Location, KubernetesVersion, ProvisioningState
```

[image]